# Extending interface vs other ways to make it global

Tags: typescript

So I have a types.ts file in the root of my dir, I can access all of the interfaces etc but once I import something it turns into a module and I can't access the stuff without importing the types file, what is the recommended way to do this? Should I do it like this and extend the basecommand in another file where I use it like:

```js
// import { Collection, Message } from 'discord.js';

type Category = 'General' | 'Admin' | 'Owner' | 'Miscellaneous';

interface BaseCommand {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  category: Category;
  usage?: string;
  examples?: string[];
  aliases?: string[];
  args?: boolean;
  guildOnly?: boolean;
  // execute: (message: Message, args: string[], commands: Collection<string, BotCommand>) => void;
}
```

```js
interface BotCommand extends BaseCommand {
  execute: (message: Message, args: string[], commands: Collection<string, BotCommand>) => void;
}
```

Or is there another way to use the BotCommand directly from the types.ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define [global-modifying-module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html) declaration file and put it, for instance, in the root directory of your project (as a sibling of the `tsconfig.json` file).

Here is an example `my-global-modifying-module.d.ts` file. Note the `global` keyword, which will allow any `*.ts` file in your project to access the `BaseCommand`, despite the existence of an `import` at the top of the declaration file.

```js
import { Collection, Message } from 'discord.js';

type Category = 'General' | 'Admin' | 'Owner' | 'Miscellaneous';

/**
 * Anything in the `declare global { }` scope will 
 * be available to every *.ts file in your project.
 */
declare global {

    interface BotCommand extends BaseCommand {
        execute: (
            message: Message,
            args: string[],
            commands: Collection<string, BotCommand>
        ) => void;
    }

    interface BaseCommand {
        name: string;
        description: string;
        category: Category;
        usage?: string;
        examples?: string[];
        aliases?: string[];
        args?: boolean;
        guildOnly?: boolean;
        execute: (
            message: Message,
            args: string[],
            commands: Collection<string, BotCommand>
        ) => void;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is this good practice tho? Isn’t there a cleaner way using the the ts config?

Comment: As far as I know, if we want to use `import ...` in our project, and if we also want to add some types to the global scope, then using `declare global { }` in a `*.d.ts` file is a good practice. I am not aware of a cleaner approach that uses the `tsconfig.json` file. If you find one, though, I would like to know about it.